# JWT Web Token Authentification

Tags: token

I am developing an Angular and NodeJS application.
I would like to set up an authentication service.

When a user connects to my application, the server sends him a token valid for 30 minutes. I regenerate the token every time the other one expires.

But there is a problem: If a user steals my token (I don't know how), he can get my session back on his computer.

How can this problem be solved?

Thank you !

Comment: This is called CSRF attack. You can view more on this topic.

Comment: May be better if this question is in https://security.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

If anyone get your token, then the server will consider that as you.
The point is which one do you want to protect: the algorithm or the key(token).
Token is like a gateway to a building. To enter the building, you usually have to register to customer service, switch your ID for an access-card. That access-card is your jwt token. If someone steal the access-card, they can access the building.

Now, You can model your authentication like the office building, there are several level of access. So even if the token is somehow stolen, their access is limited. For example:

1. Common User
2. Admin
3. Super Admin

Maybe for super-admin, you don't just use token but validate the IP address or use another method. You can google more, there is no fixed rule, it depends on the security level which you wish to impose. The basic is those 3 above